# Cannot receive messages from Vert.x MQTT Server

Tags: java, mqtt, publish-subscribe, vert.x

I am trying to get some Paho- based clients to work with the Vert.x MQTT Server. I am trying to publish to a test Topic which my receiving client is subscribed to. I am having difficulty getting a message from my client publisher to my client subscriber.

Using verious examples I have seen on the Internet, I have put together an MQTT Broker. The code for the Vert.x MQTT Broker code is below:

```
public class MQTTBroker
{      
   public MQTTBroker()
   {
      MqttServerOptions opts = new MqttServerOptions();
      opts.setHost("localhost");
      opts.setPort(1883);

      MqttServer server = MqttServer.create(Vertx.vertx(),opts);

      server.endpointHandler(endpoint -> {
      System.out.println("MQTT client [" + endpoint.clientIdentifier() + "] request to connect, clean session = " + endpoint.isCleanSession());
      endpoint.accept(false);

      if("Test_Send".equals(endpoint.clientIdentifier()))
      {
         doPublish(endpoint);

         handleClientDisconnect(endpoint);
      }
      else
      {
          handleSubscription(endpoint);
          handleUnsubscription(endpoint);
          handleClientDisconnect(endpoint);
      }
     }).listen(ar -> {
      if (ar.succeeded()) {
           System.out.println("MQTT server is listening on port " + ar.result().actualPort());
       } else {
           System.out.println("Error on starting the server");
           ar.cause().printStackTrace();
       }
   });
 }

  protected void handleSubscription(MqttEndpoint endpoint) {
     endpoint.subscribeHandler(subscribe -> {
         List grantedQosLevels = new ArrayList < > ();
         for (MqttTopicSubscription s: subscribe.topicSubscriptions()) {
             System.out.println("Subscription for " + s.topicName() + " with QoS " + s.qualityOfService());
             grantedQosLevels.add(s.qualityOfService());
        }
        endpoint.subscribeAcknowledge(subscribe.messageId(), grantedQosLevels);
    });
}

protected void handleUnsubscription(MqttEndpoint endpoint) {
    endpoint.unsubscribeHandler(unsubscribe -> {
        for (String t: unsubscribe.topics()) {
            System.out.println("Unsubscription for " + t);
        }
        endpoint.unsubscribeAcknowledge(unsubscribe.messageId());
    });
}

protected void publishHandler(MqttEndpoint endpoint) {
     endpoint.publishHandler(message -> {
     endpoint.publishAcknowledge(message.messageId());
     }).publishReleaseHandler(messageId -> {
         endpoint.publishComplete(messageId);
     });
 }

protected void handleClientDisconnect(MqttEndpoint endpoint) {
    endpoint.disconnectHandler(h -> {
        System.out.println("The remote client has closed the connection.");
    });
}

protected void doPublish(MqttEndpoint endpoint) {

   // just as example, publish a message with QoS level 2
   endpoint.publish("Test_Topic",
     Buffer.buffer("Hello from the Vert.x MQTT server"),
     MqttQoS.EXACTLY_ONCE,
     false,
     false);
   publishHandler(endpoint);

   // specifing handlers for handling QoS 1 and 2
   endpoint.publishAcknowledgeHandler(messageId -> {

     System.out.println("Received ack for message = " +  messageId);

   }).publishReceivedHandler(messageId -> {

     endpoint.publishRelease(messageId);

   }).publishCompleteHandler(messageId -> {

     System.out.println("Received ack for message = " +  messageId);
   });
  }
}
```

I have a Paho client which is supposed to receive messages from the Topic it subscribes to. The code for that is below:

```
public class Receiver implements MqttCallback
{

   public Receiver()
   {     
      MqttClient client = null;

      try
      {
         MemoryPersistence persist = new MemoryPersistence(); 
         client = new MqttClient("tcp://localhost:1883",persist);
         client.setCallback(this);
         client.connect();
         client.subscribe("Test_Topic");
         System.out.println("The receiver is initialized.");
      }
      catch(Exception exe)
      {
         exe.printStackTrace();
      }
   }

   @Override
   public void connectionLost(Throwable arg0)
   {
      System.out.println("Connection is lost!");
   }

   @Override
   public void deliveryComplete(IMqttDeliveryToken arg0)
   {
      System.out.println("Delivered!");
   }

    @Override
   public void messageArrived(String theStr, MqttMessage theMsg)
   {
     System.out.println("Message from: "+theStr);

      try
      {
         String str = new String(theMsg.getPayload());
         System.out.println("Message is: "+str); 
      }
      catch(Exception exe)
      {
         exe.printStackTrace();
      }

   }

 }
```

The subscriber and the publisher are local, though they can (and will be) remote from the Broker once I deploy my applications. The Paho- based code that I use to publish is below:

```
public void publish(String theMsg)
{
   MqttClient nwclient = null;

   try
  {
      ServConfigurator serv = ServConfigurator.getInstance();
      MemoryPersistence persist = new MemoryPersistence(); 
      String url = "tcp://localhost:1883";

      nwclient = new MqttClient(url,"Test_Send",persist);

      MqttConnectOptions option = new MqttConnectOptions();
      option.setCleanSession(true);

      nwclient.connect(option);

      MqttMessage message = new MqttMessage(theMsg.getBytes());
      message.setQos(2);
      nwclient.publish("Test_Topic",message);

      nwclient.disconnect();
      nwclient.close();

   }
   catch(Exception exe)
   {
       exe.printStackTrace();
   }
}
```

Note that I am publishing a hard- coded string (for testing purposes) from the Broker (as shown in the doPublish method) though it should be noted that I am catching the publisher client's attempt to publish in my endpoint handler. Unfortunately, while I have no problem connecting the Subscriber and the Publisher to the Broker, for some reason the message is not getting to the Subscriber. I have tried various things, but while the publisher client actually publishes to the Broker, for some reason the Broker's publish fails to send the string to the subscriber.

I am pretty sure I am missing something here, but I cannot think what it could be. Can anyone help me to get this to work???

Thanks in advance for any help or insights.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the MQTT server receives a message from the publisher so that the endpoint.publishHandler is called passing it the message, I don't see any logic in your code to get the topic and search for the subscribers (endpoints) registered for that topic and sending them the message.
At same time I don't see that you code save in some way references between subscriber endpoints and subscribed topics for doing the above research.
Remember that the MQTT server is not a broker, it doesn't take care of a list of subscribed clients on topics for you; you can build a broker on top of it which should be something you are trying to do ?

Comment: Actually, it turns out you are right. I put together a server and thought I was using a broker. This is actually a good thing, because I can make the broker anything I want. I have my clients receiving messages now and will build up a nice, custom infrastructure. Thanks for the insight.